# reset my jQuery plugin on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is in relation to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767419/multiple-instances-of-my-jquery-plugin-on-one-page) about the jQuery plugin I'm writing. I've tried to come up with the answer myself, but I'm stuck again!

Essentially, I'm trying to reset my plugin on resize. I've got a function that waits until the user has stopped resizing the browser and then calls the resize function, but I'm struggling with how to destroy and then re-wrap the elements. The only reason I need to do this is because the width and height of the lines that animate around the links is fixed in the 'wrap' function and I need to reset them. If there is a better way to do this I'd love to learn it.

My code is below:

```
;

// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
(function () {
    var method;
    var noop = function () {};
    var methods = [
            'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
            'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
            'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
            'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
        ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());



(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    // **********************************
    // ***** Start: Private Members *****
    var pluginName = 'onFancyLinks',
        version = '1.0';
    // ***** Fin: Private Members *****
    // ********************************

    // *********************************
    // ***** Start: Public Methods *****
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            //"this" is a jquery object on which this plugin has been invoked.
            return this.each(function (index) {
                var $this = $(this);
                var data = $this.data(pluginName);
                // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
                if (!data) {
                    var settings = {
                        lineColor: '#fff',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        wrapperClass: 'fancy-link',
                        linesClass: 'line',
                        transDuration: '.5',
                        transEase: 'ease-in-out'
                    };
                    if (options) {
                        $.extend(true, settings, options);
                    }

                    $this.data(pluginName, {
                        target: $this,
                        settings: settings
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        wrap: function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data(pluginName),
                    opts = data.settings,
                    //wrapping div
                    wrapper = '<div class="' + opts.wrapperClass + '"></div>',
                    lines = {
                        top: '<div class="' + opts.linesClass + ' line-top">&nbsp;</div>',
                        right: '<div class="' + opts.linesClass + ' line-right">&nbsp;</div>',
                        bottom: '<div class="' + opts.linesClass + ' line-bottom">&nbsp;</div>',
                        left: '<div class="' + opts.linesClass + ' line-left">&nbsp;</div>'
                    };

                var $wrapper = $this.wrap(wrapper).parent();
                $wrapper.append(lines.top, lines.right, lines.bottom, lines.left);

                //setup transition duration of lines animation
                $wrapper.find('.' + opts.linesClass).css({
                    /*transition: 'all ' + opts.transDuration + ' ' + opts.transEase,*/
                    backgroundColor: opts.lineColor,
                    borderWidth: opts.lineWidth
                });

                var topBottom = $wrapper.find('.line-top, .line-bottom'),
                    leftRight = $wrapper.find('.line-left, .line-right'),
                    elemWidth = $wrapper.outerWidth(),
                    elemHeight = $wrapper.outerHeight();


                var tl = new TimelineMax({
                    paused: true
                });

                tl.to(topBottom, opts.transDuration, {
                    width: elemWidth - 1
                }).to(leftRight, opts.transDuration, {
                    height: elemHeight - 1
                }, '-=' + opts.transDuration); //at the same time as the one above

                $this.off('hover').hover(function () {
                    tl.play();
                }, function () {
                    tl.reverse();
                });


                return methods.resize.apply($this);

            });
        },
        resize: function () {
            //check when resize has stopped
            var $this = $(this),
                rtime = new Date(1, 1, 2000, 12),
                timeout = false,
                delta = 200;


            $(window).resize(function () {
                rtime = new Date();
                if (timeout === false) {
                    timeout = true;
                    setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
                }
            });

            function resizeend() {
                if (new Date() - rtime < delta) {
                    setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
                } else {
                    timeout = false;
                    //resize has stopped - do something
                    return methods.destroy.apply($this);
                }
            }

        },
        destroy: function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            pluginName.prototype.destroy.call($this);
            return methods.wrap.apply($this);
        }
    };
    // ***** Fin: Public Methods *****
    // *******************************

    // *****************************
    // ***** Start: Supervisor *****
    $.fn[pluginName] = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist in jQuery.' + pluginName);
        }
    };
    // ***** Fin: Supervisor *****
    // ***************************
})(jQuery, window, document);

$(function() {

        var v1 = $('.flink2').onFancyLinks({
            lineColor: '#f00',
            lineWidth: 1,
            transDuration: '.3'
        });

        var v2 = $('#flink').onFancyLinks({
            lineColor: '#ff0',
            lineWidth: 1,
            transDuration: '0.3'
        });


        v1.onFancyLinks('wrap');
        v2.onFancyLinks('wrap');

    });
```

HTML:

```
<a class="flink2" href="http://www.google.co.uk">View Google</a>
<a class="flink2" href="http://www.google.co.uk">View Bubbon</a>
<a id="flink" href="http://www.visarc.co.uk">View Visarc Site</a>
```

Comment: Apologies - here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/owennicol/xhuxk/39/ which for some reason is failing to run now!

Comment: Line 143 in your JavaScript is causing the fiddle to fail, and I'm not sure what that line is supposed to achieve. Is pluginName supposed to be an object that has its own destroy function you're looking to call? It looks like pluginName is a string ('onFancyLinks') defined on line 29 of your code, which does not have destroy defined in its prototype.

Comment: @marck - thanks for looking at my question. Yes, it was supposed to be an object that has it's own destroy function, which then re-runs when the browser is resized. This is supposed to re-calculate the width/height of the lines.

Comment: Here is my updated fiddle with the errors taken care of: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/owennicol/xhuxk/42/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you're looking for:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhuxk/43/)

methods.destroy() modifications:

```
destroy: function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $thisWrapper = $(this).parent(),
        $origParent = $(this).parent().parent();
    $this.appendTo($origParent);
    $thisWrapper.remove();
    return methods.wrap.apply($this);
}
```

Increased delta for setTimeout to avoid excessive DOM manipulations:

```
    delta = 1000;
```

Ideally, you would modify your plugin such that it could update the existing elements without having to remove then re-add elements to the DOM. However, in this case where the rewrap only happens on resize and only affects a few elements, it seems fine.

If you're looking to share this plugin, you should reconsider and look at breaking out some of the code from your wrap() method.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to work perfectly. I'm sorry, I'm not entirely sure I get what you mean about breaking out the code in the wrap() method? Do you mean separate it out into a few more methods?

Comment: Yes, in other words, your wrap() method does too many things. If you segment it into multiple methods, each in charge of fewer tasks, as a side effect alternative solutions to this "remove then redraw" method should become apparent.