# how using global variables in jquery plugin multi-instantiable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In my plugin I use global functions to read/write the value from every part of my plugin.
This works fine if I use the plugin only for an element but if I am using it for multiple elements I have a problem (globals are overwritten).

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    'use strict';

    var globalParams = {},
        opts = {};

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        opts = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var that = this;
            var el = $this.attr("id");
            globalParams.name = opts.name;
            globalParams.color = opts.color;
            globalParams.car = opts.car;

            debug.call(that, el);

            $this.on('click', '.btn', function() {
                debug.call(that, el);
            });
        });
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
        name: "",
        color: "",
        car: ""
    };

    function debug(el) {
        console.log('opts_' +el);
        console.log(opts);
        console.log('globalParams_' +el);
        console.log(globalParams);
    }

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

multi-instante plugin

```
$(function() {
    $('#one').myPlugin({
        name: "Bar",
        color: "blue",
        car: "Audi"
    });

    $('#two').myPlugin({
        name: "Foo",
        color: "red",
        car: "BMW"
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div id="one"><button class="btn">Click ONE</button></div>
<div id="two"><button class="btn">Click TWO</button></div>
```

This is the log of (init) debug call, and it's ok.

```
//opts_one = Object { name="Bar",  color="blue",  car="Audi"}
//globalParams_one = Object { name="Bar",  color="blue",  car="Audi"}

//opts_two = Object { name="Foo",  color="red",  car="BMW"}
//globalParams_two = Object { name="Foo",  color="red",  car="BMW"}
```

And now if I click on #one btn my result is always this. It's wrong!

```
//opts_one = Object { name="Foo",  color="red",  car="BMW"}
//globalParams_one = Object { name="Foo",  color="red",  car="BMW"}
```

I thought the plugin global variables are global only within the plugin scope..
Where mistake? How could I do? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer scope can't be used for data specific to any particular invocation of the plugin.

Typically such data is stored against each initialized DOM element using jQuery's `.data()`, while the outer scope is used for static data and any utility functions.

It is also typical :

- to write the initialisation code as an `init` method.
- in addition to `init`, to allow for other plugin methods, such as your `debug`. It's also a good idea to include a `destroy` method.

Here's an example :

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    //static vars
    var pluginName = 'myPlugin';

    // utility functions here
    ...

    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            var that this;
            var data = this.data(pluginName);
            if(!data) { // if plugin has not been initialized on this element
                var defaults = {
                    name: "",
                    color: "",
                    car: ""
                };
                var opts = $.extend(true, defaults, options);
                this.data(pluginName, {
                    name: opts.name,
                    color: opts.color,
                    car: opts.car,
                    el: this.attr('id')
                });
                this.on('click.' + pluginName, '.btn', function() {
                    methods.debug.call($(that));
                });
            }
        },
        debug: function () {
            var data = this.data(pluginName);
            console.dir(data);
        },
        destroy: function () {
            this.data(pluginName, null);
            this.off('click.' + pluginName);
        }
        // ... other methods
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        return this.each(function() {
            var method = options.method || 'init';
            if(methods[method]) {
                methods[method].call($(this), options);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

*untested*

Note that the plugin itself is just a small supervisor function that decides which method to use, then calls it. A better (and more complicated) version of the supervisor would allow the method to be specified separately from the `options` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767419/multiple-instances-of-my-jquery-plugin-on-one-page) for example.

Invoke as follows :

```
$(function() {
    $('#one').myPlugin({
        name: "Bar",
        color: "blue",
        car: "Audi"
    }).myPlugin({method:'debug'});

    $('#two').myPlugin({
        name: "Foo",
        color: "red",
        car: "BMW"
    }).myPlugin({method:'debug'});
});
```

Comment: Thank you, although this is a different pattern than my. Could I use data() or this.option, this.params.name instead of globals var using my pattern?

Comment: Yes, my pattern is different from yours but not so very different; both patterns have (i) a self-executing outer wrapper, (ii) members in the scope of the outer wrapper, (iii) an expression that defines the plugin as a method of the `jQuery.fn` namespace. All I have done is to refactor your code in order to overcome the fundamental flaw in the original code; namely that stateful members in the outer scope cannot be shared by different DOM elelemts on which the plugin is invoked.

Comment: Yes, you could set ` data(pluginName, {...})` in your pattern as it stands, but there's no need to do so unless that data is going to be used, and it should only ever be used by plugin methods other than `init`, or by an event handler attached during initialisation. If your plugin has no such methods or event handlers, then it need not be set.